# Is there any possibility to insert new SlideMaster?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I am trying to implement adding a slide into a presentation, but this slide has different main master (theme, footers etc.). Is there any way to add new Master Slide into a presentation using Interop.PowerPoint?

I researched official documentation, but found no direct ways like there are in other libraries, like `presentation.Masters.Add(newMaster);`

Comment: _"differrent...theme, footers"_ - I'm not even sure PowerPoint allows that, programming or not.  Besides, any code to show?  Otherwise your question is kinda too-broad which might make it off-topic for SO

Comment: You can't do anything that PowerPoint itself doesn't do. Office Interop uses *the same API* as the VBA macros, which means you can record a macro with the steps you want and inspect the calls

Comment: As the [Master object's docs show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.master) a presentation can have a different master for each page type (title, slide, notes). You can't have multiple masters per type. If you want to base eg a Slides master on a different design, you can add a hidden slide with that design and clone it as needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of PowerPoint's development history, the object names are a bit odd.

```
Presentation.Designs.Add
```

[Designs.Add Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff761369(v=office.14))